# How to make a double button door

Tags: minecraft-redstone

How can I make a double button door? By that, I mean that two people have to switch the same button at the same time to open a door for a short time, and then these door would close up behind them. Please explain how to do this or link a tutorial.

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Answer (score 4):

AND gate into a pulse extender. The time provided by the buttons themselves (1s for stone button, 1.5 for wooden) should provide enough time so that they "must be pressed simultaneously" is decently tight but doable. The pulse extender (using 2 comparators) will provide enough time to pass through the door and close it afterwards.

This version of the contraption will work with any edition of Minecraft that supports these components (so pretty much every except for the most stripped-down ones like the 4k, Raspberry Pi, or JE older than 1.5).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cant Redstone signal pass-through blocks using a repeater? So have one button power a sticky piston with a Redstone block on it to power the Redstone line, then where the second button is, have a repeater, then a gap, the more dust line, and where the gap is, have the second button power a sticky piston to push a solid block, such as stone, to the spot right in between the repeater and dust line.[image: pretty bad diagram, but I think you get the picture]

Comment: The block with a P on it is the sticky piston, the small square on it is the button, the horizontal red line is the dust line, that weird black line with to line sticking up off of it with red dots on the end is the repeater, the block with the S on it is the stone, and the red block is the redstone block. I used chrome canvas so it is quite horrible

Comment: As for the door, you can use pretty much any door design online, as long as it matches your edition of Minecraft.

Comment: I don't think this design will work. Doesn't pushing blocks with redstone on them with pistons break the redstone?

Comment: @nick012000 Eh, this design has its deal of problems but it will work.. partially. First, in Java Edition buttons pop off sides of pistons (and cause the piston to zero-tick (teleport) the block 1 block away.) So the first issue is moving the buttons at the very least to the backside of the pistons. Next, you're right with the redstone: activating left P will break the first redstone dust, in effect *fixing* the contraption which was constantly powering the line. The third issue is the whole left piston and its redstone block are completely unneeded, button alone is enough.

Comment: The repeater, block and piston (sideways or down, not up) placed in such way that the piston extending puts the block between the piston and the dust) is an alternative version of the AND gate, so assuming the piston in the drawing on the right is sideways and extended, this part works alright. The one problem remaining is lack of a pulse extender - the door will only remain open as long as both buttons are pressed simultaneously, which is usually too short for two players to pass.

Comment: I drew this quickly, and not as a complete schematic, which was bad on my part, just to show the idea. There was no Redstone Dust on the moving block, the block only moves to transfer the signal. Looking back, I forgot entirely about AND gates, which would have been much simpler.

Comment: @Big_Chungus Yeah, I know what you meant with the right part. It IS an AND gate, just an alternative build. But I'm still baffled at the idea behind the purpose of the piston with redstone block. Other than acting as a noisy, expensive and bulky repeater, I don't see why.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking when I did that part, I had my mind on sticky pistons, and that just slipped in there.